# Help to solve my problems with python LIST?

Tags: python

```
author_A = [['book_x',1,10],['book_y',2,20],['book_z',3,30]]
author_B = [['book_s',5,10],['book_t',2,20],['book_z',3,30]]

author_A AND author_B = ['book_z',3,30]
             author_A = [['book_x',1,10],['book_y',2,20]]
             author_B = [['book_s',5,10],['book_t',2,20]]
             ---------------------------------------------
```

I Want present data like this

```
     author     quantity   Amount($)
      A&B        3            30
      A          3            30
      B          7            30
      total      13           90
```

I DO NOT Want present data like this !!! in this case it's ADDED duplicate ['book_z',3,30]

```
         author   quantity   Amount($)
          A         6            60
          B         10           60
          total     16           120
```

that is my problems ,Anybody Please help me to sove this problems.
 Thanks everybody

Comment: Can you show some actual Python source code that demonstrates what you have got so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
author_A = [['book_x',1,10],['book_y',2,20],['book_z',3,30]]
author_B = [['book_s',5,10],['book_t',2,20],['book_z',3,30]]

def present(A, B):
  Aset = set(tuple(x) for x in A)
  Bset = set(tuple(x) for x in B)
  both = Aset & Bset
  justA = Aset - both
  justB = Bset - both
  totals = [0, 0]
  print "%-12s %-12s %12s" % ('author', 'quantity', 'Amount($)')
  for subset, name in zip((both, justA, justB), ('A*B', 'A', 'B')):
    tq = sum(x[1] for x in subset)
    ta = sum(x[2] for x in subset)
    totals[0] += tq
    totals[1] += ta
    print ' %-11s  %-11d    %-11d' % (name, tq, ta)
  print ' %-11s  %-11d    %-11d' % ('total', totals[0], totals[1])

present(author_A, author_B)
```

I've tried to reproduce your desired weird format with some numbers left-aligned and totally funky spacing, but I'm sure you'll need to tweak the formatting in the various print statements to get the exact (and totally weird) formatting effect of your examples.  However, apart from the spacing and left- vs right- alignment of the output, this should otherwise be exactly what you request.

Comment: Thanks.Alex Martelli.
in this case i need improve more and A,and B.example C and D .so i will add C,and D to the mothod present(A,B,C,D)
and Now i want flexible with present(list of author).
Thank your for more helping!

Comment: @python (nice nick!-), computing the whole powerset of authors is harder while quite possible esp. with itertools.combinations -- but why not open a separate question about it (ideally omitting the formatting quirks;-) since it's very different from this question, i.e. if you want "all authors", "all but one", "all but two", ... "just one author and none of the others", that's a "powerset", and there are specific subtleties in computing and dealing w/it correctly (skipping empty combinations, etc, etc). I would recommend accepting an answer to this one and opening another (w/o formatting;-).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the intersections and exclusive ones like this...

```
A_and_B = [a for a in author_A if a in author_B]
only_A = [a for a in author_A if a not in author_B]
only_B = [b for b in author_B if b not in author_A]
```

then it is only a matter of printing them...

```
print '%s %d %d' % tuple(A_and_B)
print '%s %d %d' % tuple(only_A)
print '%s %d %d' % tuple(only_B)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Upvote is cautious - not sure I understand the question, but AFAICT this is a good answer. Pedantic criticism - the total is missing.

Comment: i wanted him to tweak this to get the required script for himself.. for as I see it he is learning python, so I did not want to give a complete script that does what he needs without even reading the code :).. but yeah, Alex's solution is way cool. I have to get used to using sets :D.. thanks for the vote btw

Comment: I agree Alex's answer, inc. his use of set, is excellent - but I still think using three comprehensions and no set intersections/differences has a slight readability edge. Probably not as efficient for large datasets, though.

Comment: "slight readability edge"... that's what makes me looove list comprehensions :D

Answer (score 0):

```
books = {
    'A':[['book_x',1,10],['book_y',2,20]],
    'B':[['book_s',5,10],['book_t',2,20]],
    'A & B':[['book_z',3,30]],
}
for key in books:
    quantity = []
    amount = []
    for item in books[key]:
        quantity.append(item[1])
        amount.append(item[2])
    print ("%s\t%s\t%s") % (key,sum(quantity),sum(amount))
```